# Chaining Requests using BlueBird/ Request-Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm using the request-promise module and have found no mention of how to chain requests. I'm currently following their syntax of:

```
request({options})
  .then(function(result){...})
  .catch(function(error){...})
```

However I want to be able to use Promise.all and try to make multiple calls at the same time and wait for them to all resolve and then proceed with other calls. For example I want to:

1. Make a call to one app creating a User.
2. AT THE SAME TIME, make a call creating an Address.
3. Promise.all([UserCall, AddressCall]).then({function to deal with results])?

Also I have been working with my function in module.exports = {...}. Does this require me to be outside of exports and have them declare as separate variables?

From what I understand its seems as if I have to do something like:

```
var UserCall = function(req,res){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    request({options})? //To make the call to create a new user?
  // Then something with resolve and reject
```

Any help is much appreciated. I think I may be mixing up basic BlueBird concepts and trying to use them with request-promise.

Comment: Yes, just use `Promise.all([request({…}), request({…})])`. What exactly is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: No, you should not use the `new Promise` constructor if `request(…)` already returns a promise

Comment: I tried using `Promise.all([request({…}), request({…})]).then(function(results){...})`. However for some reason I am getting null or undefined results from the 2 requests. I did some console logs and it seems as if the .then function is not waiting for the results to come back. Am I supposed to put a `.then(function (result){ return result})` for each `request({...})`?

Comment: Hm, you can try that, but actually `Promise.all` should call `.then` by itself on the inputs

Comment: Ok I got it to work by have `Promise.all([function1, function2]).then({...})` where function1 and function2 have `return request({...})`

Comment: No, that doesn't work, it doesn't actually call the functions.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
var BPromise = require('bluebird');
var rp = require('request-promise');

BPromise.all([
    rp(optionsForRequest1),
    rp(optionsForRequest2)
])
    .spread(function (responseRequest1, responseRequest2) {
        // Proceed with other calls...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // Will be called if at least one request fails.
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Like you said, you can accomplish this using the `all` API.

Refer to the documentation here: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

**Example:**

```
    var self = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        Promise.all([self.createUser, self.createAddress])done(
            // code path when all promises are completed
            // OR should any 1 promise return with reject()
            function() { resolve(); }
        );
    })
```

As noted in the code, the `.all()` callback code path will get called as well when any 1 of the defined promise in `promises` gets rejected.

Comment: As @Bergi said, you should not create new promises. Just call `Promise.all(  self.createUser(), self.createAddress() ).then( ... )`

Comment: I'm currently doing `Promise.all([request({…}), request({…})]).then(function(result){...}).catch(function(err){...})` but am running into null or undefined resullts from the 2 requests as stated in my comment above.

Comment: `Promise.all` does take an array, not multiple parameters